# Attempt to read property "file" on null

Tags: laravel

I keep getting the file on null error and can't seem to find why he can't locate the file?

```
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <img height="62" src="{{asset($user->userdetail->file)}}" alt="">

                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Userdetail Model

```
class UserDetail extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['file'];
    protected $uploads = '/img/avatar/';

    public function getFileAttribute($userdetail){
        return $this->uploads . $userdetail;
    }
}
```

user model

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'is_active',
        'email',
        'photo_id',
        'password',
    ];

    public function userdetail(){
        return $this->belongsTo(UserDetail::class);
    }
```

Location of file
[image]

Migration userdetails

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('file');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

[image]
user
[image]

ddump of $user

[image]

Comment: yes is only 3 users and i all gave them id 1

Comment: There is so much wrong here
Your relationship is wrong, should be ```hasOne(UserDetail::class)```
You can't pass an argument to an attribute mutator, you might want ```public function getFileAttribute(){ return $this->uploads . $this->file; }```

Comment: yes u can pass an argument it worked fine with model photo and user but because i want seperate table for my product photos and user profile photos i added a new model

Comment: the relationship is correct belongsto

Comment: Sorry, my bad, yes it takes the value of the column, you are right. But the way you have set your relationship and table up is still wrong. It should be hasOne and you will need a user_id column on the user_details table as the foreign key

Comment: No, it should be hasOne, and you need to specify the foreign key as photo_id (if that is the id of the user who's photo it is) or you need to add a user_id foreign key to the user_detail table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the relation.

```
   public function photo(){
    return $this->belongsTo(UserDetail::class);
}
```

my problem was the name of the function i named it userdetail and then it will look for userdetail_id instead i needed it to name photo because then it will look for photo_id

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the relationship for photo.
make this function in user model and place the name of the correct model

```
public function photo(){ return $this->hasOne(UserDetails::class, 'id', 'photo_id'); }
```

Comment: share the dump of the user

Comment: but is still don't understand why it didn't work with belongsto normally it should look for the id no?

Comment: Actually if user_details table have user_id key then you can use belongsTo relationship. You have photo_id in users table that hasOne relation to the photo record.

Comment: is very strange because before i had User and Photo and it worked fine
```
  public function photo(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Photo::class);
    }
```
and photo
```
   protected $fillable=['file'];
    protected $uploads = '/';
   // protected $guarded=['id'];
    // get{property or field}Attribute
   public function getFileAttribute($photo){
        return $this->uploads . $photo;
    }
}
```

Comment: In user model you have to make hasOne relationship with photo